# Datagrid View Button repeats

Tags: c#, datagridview, button, repeat

> **EXACT** duplicate of [Datagrid View Button
>   repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167136/datagrid-view-button-repeat)

I have added button to datagrid view but when ever the function is called more than once then new button adds I need to stop this addition

```
  void AddtoGrid()
    {
        try
        {                
            table = new DataTable();
            bcol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            bcol.HeaderText = "Action ";
            bcol.Text = "Delete";
            bcol.Name = "deleteUserButton";
            bcol.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;                

            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Type");
            table.Columns.Add("Status");
            table.Columns.Add("Date Created");


            for (int i = 0; i < userAction.UserName.ToArray().Length; i++)
            {
                row = table.NewRow();
                asc.Add(userAction.UserName[i]);
                row["Name"] = userAction.UserName[i];
                row["Type"] = userAction.UserType[i];
                row["Status"] = userAction.UserStatus[i];
                row["Date Created"] = userAction.DateCrea[i];
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            UsersView.DataSource = table;
            UsersView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;//To remove extra row at the end
            UsersView.Columns.Add(bcol);
        }
        catch (Exception ca)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ca.ToString());
        }
    }//End Function for Getting Present Users
```

Comment: **EXACT** duplicate of [Datagrid View Button repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167136/datagrid-view-button-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the method up in two:

1.) To setup the grid structure
2.) To add new rows

```
public void SetupDataGridView()
{
            table = new DataTable();
            bcol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            bcol.HeaderText = "Action ";
            bcol.Text = "Delete";
            bcol.Name = "deleteUserButton";
            bcol.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;                

            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Type");
            table.Columns.Add("Status");
            table.Columns.Add("Date Created");

            UsersView.DataSource = table;
            UsersView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;//To remove extra row at the end
            UsersView.Columns.Add(bcol);
}

public void PopulateDataGridView()
{

            for (int i = 0; i < userAction.UserName.ToArray().Length; i++)
            {
                row = table.NewRow();
                asc.Add(userAction.UserName[i]);
                row["Name"] = userAction.UserName[i];
                row["Type"] = userAction.UserType[i];
                row["Status"] = userAction.UserStatus[i];
                row["Date Created"] = userAction.DateCrea[i];
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

}
```

And this is still a suboptimal approach, but that's the most anyone can do for someone with your skills.

You lack basic knowledge of programming and object oriented programming in particular. Get a book (e.g. chris sells' book on windows forms programming) read it, and then come back. You will benefit from it!

Comment: Falcon? More like Blue Falcon.

Comment: I suppose. Good answer anyways.